# Amazon s3 static image hosting vs keeping on Heroku

Tags: amazon-s3

Is it better to keep my images on amazons3 vs heroku? even though they're not very big? Using s3 is a bit more work but maybe it's worth the effort?

Comment: Are you have issues with your images on Heroku? What problems are you having that you feel you need to move your images to S3?

Comment: Doesn't keeping the images on Heroku hog the dynos for longer than if they're on S3?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Please elaborate, your question is very vague.